# Почему не запускается тестирование?

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Помогите пож с тестом.

```
def factr():
    if(n==0):
        return 1
    return factr(n-1)*n

def test(factr):
    if(n!=0):
        return 1
    '''
    >>> compare([factr(n)>0])
    1
    >>> compare(0)
    0
    '''
if(__name__=="__main__"):
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(verbose=True)
```

пишет

```
3 items had no tests:
    __main__
    __main__.factr
    __main__.test
0 tests in 3 items.
0 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Comment: Судя по вашему коду (а также по предыдущему вопросу), у вас очень слабое представление о том, что такое функция, аргументы функции и всё такое, советую почитать какую-нибудь литературу по основам Python, прежде чем тесты писать

Answer (score 2):

Doctest-комментарии пишутся непосредственно в тестируемом методе.

Кстати, незачем сокращать имя до `factr`, байты нынче дёшевы. Ещё у вас была ошибка в том, что метод не принимал ни одного параметра.

```
def factorial(n):
    '''
    >>> factorial(0)
    1
    >>> factorial(1)
    1
    >>> [factorial(n) for n in range (5)]
    [1, 1, 2, 6, 24]
    '''
    if (n == 0):
        return 1
    return factorial(n - 1) * n

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Вот вам ещё несколько интересных кейсов. Подумайте, что должна выдавать функция при таких входных значениях.

```
    '''
    >>> factorial(-1)

    >>> factorial(0.5)

    >>> factorial('abc')
    '''
```